# Hibernate OneToMany relationship: not mapped to a single propery

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, one-to-many, hibernate-onetomany

I have two tables with these primary keys:

```
  TABLE A                 TABLE B
  ----------             ----------             
 | colA     |----->     | colX     |
 | colB     |----->     | colY     |
 | colC     |----->     | colW     |
 |__________|           | colZ     |
                        |__________|
```

Basically I need to define this relationship in JPA 1.0.

I tried to map entity of tableA with this code:

```
    @OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.LAZY, cascade=CascadeType.ALL, targetEntity=TableB.class)
    @JoinColumns({      
            @JoinColumn(name="colX", referencedColumnName="colA", insertable=false, updatable=false),
            @JoinColumn(name="colY", referencedColumnName="colB", insertable=false, updatable=false),
            @JoinColumn(name="colW", referencedColumnName="colC", insertable=false, updatable=false)
        })      

private Set<TableB> tableB;

..get and set
```

All I get is this error :

```
    org.hibernate.AnnotationException: Unable to map collection TableB

    Caused by: org.hibernate.AnnotationException: referencedColumnNames(colA, colB, colC) of tableB referencing tableA not mapped to a single property
```

Any help ?

EDIT*

Either Table A and TableB got @EmbeddedId primary key class with their own pk cols stated on top.

The code below explains better the situation

```
// TABLE A PKey Entity

@Embeddable
class TableAPKey 
{
    @Column
    String colA; // get and set
    @Column
    String colB; // get and set
    @Column
    String colC; // get and set
}   

// TABLE A Entity

class TableA
{
    @EmbeddedId
    TableAPKey key; // get and set
}
// TABLE B PKey entity

@Embeddable
class TableBPKey 
{
    @Column
    String colX; // get and set
    @Column
    String colY; // get and set
    @Column
    String colW; // get and set
    @Column
    String colZ; // get and set NOT USED IN RELATIONSHIP with TableA
}   

// TABLE B Entity

class TableB
{
    @EmbeddedId
    TableBPKey key; // get and set
}
```

Comment: Are `colA`, `colB`, `colC` the composite primary key of `TableA`? Please post the ID fields of `TableA` entity.

Comment: I've improved the question by inserting definition of entity A and B

Comment: Does B have a relationship to A?

Answer (score 0):

Your mapping is partly incorrect. Try the following:

```
class TableA {

    // ...
    @OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.LAZY, cascade=CascadeType.ALL, targetEntity=TableB.class, mappedBy = "key.tableA")
    private Set<TableB> tableB;
}


@Embeddable
class TableBPKey {

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumns({
        @JoinColumn(name = "colX", referencedColumnName = "colA"),
        @JoinColumn(name = "colY", referencedColumnName = "colB")
        @JoinColumn(name = "colW", referencedColumnName = "colC")
    })        
    private TableA tableA;

    @Column
    String colZ;

    // ...
}
```

Comment: does "key." refers to tableA or tableB primary key ?

Comment: As you reference a `Set<TableB>` it means `key` of `TableB`.

Comment: still return the same error "referencedColumnNames not mapped to a single property"

Comment: Strange, and you really don't have any more `@JoinColumns` on `TableA`?

Comment: Yes I'm sure. What does really mean "referencedColumnNames not mapped to a single property" ? I can't understand

Comment: It means that one column you mention in `referencedColumnName` has not been found in the target entity.